# How to activate anaconda environment in php-fpm shell_exec?

Tags: php, python, docker, nginx, anaconda

I have php-fpm running as nginx user in a docker container.
Dockerfile creates correct anaconda environment called 'ss' with pandas package. It works ok when I attach to the docker container.

Docker CMD runs an init.sh script:

```
. /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate /opt/conda/envs/ss
php-fpm --fpm-config /etc/php-fpm.conf
nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

Then, a PHP script runs Python script using

```
shell_exec("python ss.py");
```

This errors with:

> ImportError: No module named pandas

I tried various combinations of shell_exec where I tried activating the env before running the script, but it mostly errors out with:

> CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to
>   use 'conda activate'

How do I activate the 'ss' env for all PHP shell_exec scripts?

Comment: pandas is missing `RUN  pip install pandas`

Comment: pandas is already installed in anaconda environment

Comment: Just to clarify: the `init.sh` script runs correctly (it looks like it should), but the shell session that it runs in does not appear to carry over to the shell invoked by `shell_exec`.  Is this what you see is happening?

Comment: Exactly. The linux install guide doesn't mention it, but per macOS instructions in each new bash session, before using conda, set the PATH and run the activation scripts of your conda packages by running:

`source $HOME/miniconda/bin/activate`

That bit doesn't work. I can't modify the shell_exec calls (3rd party code) so I hope there is a way to setup the env permanently for PHP.

Answer (score 1):

you can directly use like this.

shell_exec('/root/.conda/envs/my-rdkit-env/bin/python3 ss.py');

Comment: That's exactly what I can't do. It's third-party code. I can't change shell_exec("python ss.py"); so I'm trying to find a way it executes in properly configured environment.